# Silverlight serialization XML

Tags: xml, silverlight, serialization

The user choose items in a list and click on validate button. I need to :

1. Get the selected items
2. Create a xml file with the elements
3. Save the file on server

I get the selected items without problem, create the StringWriter.
But then, I can't create a file on the user side (because not in OOB mode) and send it to the server.

How can I send my file to the server and store it on the right folder ? At my point, I have a StringWriter with all good on it (inner xml).

Thank you in advance,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) to create a file on client side in silverlight. To upload it to the server you might need a WCF/Webservice to upload the file on the server the you must be able to send the file stream directly to the service.

Comment: Thank you, I create my file with IsolatedStorage and I let you know.

Comment: No problem to store my file using IsolatedStorage. I can retreive it also. I create the web service know. Thank you.